# What is the best way to optimize a nested where clause that has multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to find a list of `ReturnItems` where the quantity of a single item being returned is more than the original ordered quantity for that item. So there are 2 different lists of objects in play here - `IEnumerable<ReturnItem>` and `IEnumerable<OrderItem>`. The problem is that depending on the source for making the return (there are multiple places in our workflow where a return can be made) the `ItemNumber` on a given `ReturnItem` may be null. In this case we would need to rely on the `ReturnItem.OrderItemId` to match it to an `OrderItem`.

I have solved the problem using LINQ, but it requires a nested for loop (under the hood) so I'm trying to avoid that if possible while also maintain readability.In other words, I want to avoid a run time of O(N^2) and look for O(N) or better but again, while maintaining readability (I know I'm asking for a lot here but I figured I'd see if anyone has a creative solution). I created a solution where I have two dictionaries for the order items. One of them, the key is the item number and the other's key is the order Item Id. This works and solves the performance problem, but I completely loose the readability.

Here is the original LINQ statement I had:

```
// ItemsForReturn = IEnumerable<ReturnItem>
// OrderItems = IEnumerable<OrderItem>

var invalidQuantityItems = message.ItemsForReturn.Where(returnItem =>
{
    var matchingOrderItemQuantity = message.OrderItems
        .Where(orderItem => orderItem.ItemNumber.Equals(returnItem.ItemNumber) || orderItem.OrderItemId == returnItem.OrderItemId)
        .Sum(orderItem => orderItem.Quantity);

    return matchingOrderItemQuantity < returnItem.Quantity;
});
```

and the corresponding types of the variables used above:

```
public class ReturnItem
{
    public int OrderItemId {get; set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    // There's more properties but these are the ones that matter
{

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId {get; set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    // There's more properties but these are the ones that matter
{
```

I expect that `var invalidQuantityItems` will be an `IEnumerable<ReturnItems>` whose quantity for an individual item is greater than the amount ordered (i.e. they're trying to return more than they ordered in the first place).

Cheers!

Comment: In general, you can optimize multiple conditions by putting the most likely condition that will end the evaluation first.

Comment: Agree with @RufusL you want your likeliest to be false conditions first, but as for optimisation, I wouldn't worry about it too much, the SQL query planner will be taking care of most of that for you, provided you have things like your indexes set up correctly.

Comment: Why don't you just always use the `int OrderItemId` field for comparison?

Comment: because depending on the source of the return creation, it may not be there. I.e. sometimes both item number and order item ID are there, sometimes it's one or the other.

Comment: How is `OrderItem` used? Is `OrderItemId` together with `ItemNumber` distinct?

Comment: `OrderItemId` by itself is distinct so adding `ItemNumber` to it would still be distinct too

Comment: So any list of `OrderItem` never has more than one element with the same `OrderItemId` besides of 0? And also any list of `OrderItem` never has more than one element with the same `ItemNumber` besides of `null`? This looks like `OrderItemId` might be a surrogate key and `ItemNumber` a natural key?

Comment: In the database, the `OrderItemId` is actually the 'natural" key. It is possible in some scenarios that there are multiple items on an order who have the same item number but different order Item Ids. It's difficult to explain on here because it's complex business rules. Lets just say for this use case that item numbers cannot be repeated for the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small correction - the time complexity of the current implementation is O(N*M) and the best you can get is O(N+M).

The problem is how to efficiently correlate the two sets. In LINQ this is achieved with [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause), and for this one-to-many type of correlation - [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join). The equivalent of the `||` criteria will be [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8) of the results of two group joins (matching sets).

Speaking about readability, LINQ and joins, the best would be using the LINQ *query* syntax (there is a reason some people also call it *comprehension* syntax).

So the query in question can efficiently (and hopefully readable) be rewritten as follows:

```
var invalidQuantityItems =
    from returnItem in message.ItemsForReturn
    join orderItem in message.OrderItems on returnItem.ItemNumber equals orderItem.ItemNumber
    into matchingOrderItems1
    join orderItem in message.OrderItems on returnItem.OrderItemId equals orderItem.OrderItemId
    into matchingOrderItems2
    let matchingOrderItemQuantity = matchingOrderItems1.Union(matchingOrderItems2)
        .Sum(orderItem => orderItem.Quantity)
    where matchingOrderItemQuantity < returnItem.Quantity
    select returnItem;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if `M` and `N` can be the same size, than isn't the complexity `O(N^2)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the dictionary approach is the best way to go.

About the readability, I think this should be not too bad:

```
var quantityByItemNumber = message.OrderItems.
    Where(i => i.ItemNumber != null).
    ToDictionary(
        i => i.ItemNumber,
        i => i.Quantity);

var quantityByOrderItemId = message.OrderItems.ToDictionary(
    i => i.OrderItemId,
    i => i.Quantity);

var invalidQuantityItems = message.ItemsForReturn.Where(returnItem =>
{
    int matchingOrderItemQuantity;
    var isNumberMatch = returnItem.ItemNumber != null) &&
        quantityByItemNumber.TryGetValue(returnItem.ItemNumber, out matchingOrderItemQuantity);

    if (!isNumberMatch)
        quantityByOrderItemId.TryGetValue(returnItem.OrderItemId, out matchingOrderItemQuantity)

    return matchingOrderItemQuantity < returnItem.Quantity;
});
```

In fact I think this is even more readable, because it does not wrongly pretend that there is more than one matching `OrderItem`, which quantities has to be summed up.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't `ToDictionary()` throw an exception if the key provided is `null`? I.E. `ToDictionary(i => i.ItemNumber,...` won't work in the event that `i.ItemNumber` is `null`? Other than that this is great.

Comment: You're right, adjusted my answer. But I was thinking at least `OrderItem` would be completely filled.

Answer (score 0):

As far as optimizing multiple conditions goes:

1. Always put the most likely conditions that will end evaluation first (you would have to determine this based on existing data or your knowledge of the system).
2. If there is not a large likelihood of one condition occurring more frequently than the other, then we can consider the evaluation itself. For example, if an `int` comparison is faster than a `string` comparison, then put the `int` comparison first.

Also, your code doesn't need a separate line to get the `Sum`; you can do it in the same expression:

```
var invalidQuantityItems = message.ItemsForReturn.Where(returnItem =>
    message.OrderItems
        .Where(orderItem =>
            orderItem.OrderItemId == returnItem.OrderItemId ||
            orderItem.ItemNumber.Equals(returnItem.ItemNumber))
        .Sum(orderItem => orderItem.Quantity) < returnItem.Quantity);
```

Comment: That's a great point about putting the most likely condition first. However, I was looking for how to avoid doing a nested for loop (because this in turn evaluates to nested foreach loops). I want to get the complexity down to O(N) if possible.